# How to assign a new column name to the sum of columns aggregated in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need to assign a name to the sum of columns aggregated in a mysql query.

This is what is tried:

```
SELECT 
     JSON_LENGTH(comments) as c_total, 
     JSON_LENGTH(likes) as l_total, 
     (c_total+l_total) as total 
FROM posts
```

Comments and likes columns holds data in json data type.
JSON_LENGTH returns the length of the array.
How can ı get the total value in above example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference select fields if they're in subqueries:

```
SELECT c_total + l_total AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT
         JSON_LENGTH(comments) as c_total,
         JSON_LENGTH(likes) as l_total,
         (c_total+l_total) as total
    FROM posts
) A
;
```

otherwise I think you have to repeat the logic:

```
SELECT 
     JSON_LENGTH(comments) as c_total, 
     JSON_LENGTH(likes) as l_total, 
     (JSON_LENGTH(comments) + JSON_LENGTH(likes)) as total 
FROM posts
;
```